# Glitchy font when running start command from ConEmu

Tags: c++, windows, vim, mingw, conemu

Before I start...

my tool chain consist of MinGW, ConEmu, and Vim to make C++ programs.

I wanted to test to see if MinGW was working by seeing if g++ was setup correctly on my system PATH, and it turned it was because I successfully compiled a simple console program that outputted the text I provided to standard out. However, I came across this...

When I do the command `start test.exe` from window's cmd shell in ConEmu (I use the `start` command because I want it in its own standalone prompt), the text looks like this.

[image]

These little white lines are annoying and I would like to know what's causing it...

When I run the standalone from the explorer it looks completely normal.

[image]

Is there something in ConEmu's settings that's causing this that anybody is aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. I just end up using the program called *cmder*. Which is practically ConEmu but with more features built on top of it.